# Publish Gitlab artifacts to Artifactory

Tags: gitlab, artifactory, gitlab-ci

I want to publish my Gitlab project's(not a maven project) artifact to JFrog Artifactory. The artifact size is 4.2 GB. 
I searched for this but mostly got links to publish Gitlab Maven project to Artifactory. My project is not a maven project.

I have a requirement to keep all source code in Gitlab and artifacts(.war, .tar.gz) in Artifactory.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for Git LFS. This is an extention to Git that allows your Gitlab repository to track artifacts without actually storing them in the repository, instead using some external filestore or artifact management server.

Artifactory supports Git LFS repositories, and you can find the documentation for setting it up [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Git+LFS+Repositories).

Comment: Thanks DarthFennec :)

Comment: I solved this by using CURL:
curl -u username:password -X PUT -T <my-filename>.tar.gz "<http://artifactory-URL>/artifactory/libs-release-local/<my-filename>.tar.gz"

Referred below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060553/how-do-i-deploy-a-file-to-artifactory-using-the-command-line